# unable to delete a row from jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

**Situation :** I am developing a spring mvc webapp , in that I am trying to provide a delete button for every row in a jqgrid , when user clicks on delete button a javascript function is executed that sends a request to controller which deletes the row from server's DB and then the row is deleted from jqgrid ,to achieve this my html is as follows :

```
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

and javascript is as follows :

```
var mydata = [{
    name: "Toronto",
    country: "Canada",
    continent: "North America"
}, {
    name: "New York City",
    country: "USA",
    continent: "North America"
}, {
    name: "Silicon Valley",
    country: "USA",
    continent: "North America"
}, {
    name: "Paris",
    country: "France",
    continent: "Europe"
}]

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ["Name", "Country", "Continent","action"],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'name',
        index: 'name',
        editable: true,
    }, {
        name: 'country',
        index: 'country',
        editable: true,
    }, {
        name: 'continent',
        index: 'continent',
        editable: true,
    },{
        name: 'conti',
        index: 'cont',
        formatter : hello,
        editable: true, 

    }],
    pager: '#pager'
});

function hello(cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
return '<a href="javascript:deleteRow(\'' + rowObject.name     
+'/');">delete</a>';
//code to remove this row from jqgrid
}
```

**Problem :** Now when delete button is pressed row is deleted from server's DB BUT i am not able to figure out how to remove row from jqgrid , i tried using `delRowData` but it requires `rowid` and i have only `rowobject` , can anyone tell me how can i remove the relevant row from jqgrid using `rowobject` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution , we can retrieve `rowId` from `options` object as follows :

```
function hello(cellvalue, options, rowObject) 
{
     return '<a href="javascript:clickFunction(\'' + options.rowId + '\');">' + "DELETE" + '</a>'; 
}
```

Then when user clicks on hyperlink "Delete" `clickFunction()` is executed , in that `delRowData()` takes in `rowId` and deletes the relevant row .

```
function clickFunction(rowid)
{
    alert(rowid);
    $('#grid').delRowData(rowid);
}
```

**Documentation :** http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter

Answer (score 0):

In general it's recommended to include `id` property in the input data. The `id` will be used to assign the value of `id` attribute to the rows (`<tr>` elements) of the grid.

It's important to know that `options` parameter of the custom formatter contains properties which could be helpful for you: `options.rowId` and `options.colModel`. You can forward `options.rowId` as an additional parameter to your `deleteRow` function.

Comment: yup, i was going through doc and figured it just right now ! anyway thanks fort he heads up